# Wake-up issues with Macbook Pro (late 2011)

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I recently bought a new Macbook pro to replace my last one, and since I got it, it has been having some issues when I wake it up from sleep.

a) The display freezes for three seconds each time, so after it switches on, it takes three seconds before it shows the correct battery life and allows me to type.

b) Despite connecting to the internet OK (Sparrow works fine), Chrome and Safari both report no internet connection until the laptop is restarted (a pain in the ass) (happens on several networks)

c) VLC player wont resume play of a DVD (or rather, it will but with no sound).

My previous laptop (2010 gen, Lion) didn't do any of these three and I'm wondering - are they common / easily fixed, or should I head back into the Apple store with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting your SMC. It's inter alia responsible for the opening and closing behavior of your MacBook Pro:

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to the Mac if its not already connected.
3. On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
4. Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
5. Press the power button to turn on the computer.
   ***Note***: The LED on the MagSafe power adapter may change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC.

Source: [Apple Support pages](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964)

Comment: That sorted out my WiFi problem, and it doesn't 'seem' to be freezing anymore - which is pretty much all that matters, so thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome :)